# generic function to cast spark dataframe columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, typeclass

I wrote the following function which cast a spark dataframe column but I want to make it use typed functions:

```
def castCol(newName: String, previosuNmae: String, datatType: DataType): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn(newName, col(previosuNmae).cast(datatType))
```

I want to rather make it like:

```
def castCol[DataType](newName: String, previosuNmae: String): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn(newName, col(previosuNmae).cast(DataType))
```

but this doesn't work.
Do you know whow to pass the dataType to the function as a type and not an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def castCol[T<:DataType](newColName: String, newColType:T, previousColName: String): DataFrame = 
    df.withColumn(newColName, col(previousColName).cast(newColType))
```

Hope it helps